Reading Mirzakhani's curve counting result
In Mirzakhani's paper Counting mapping class group orbits on hyperbolic surfaces, Theorem 1.1 states: Let $X$ be a complete hyperbolic metric on $S_{g,n}$, $\Gamma\subset\text{Mod}_{g,n}$ a finite index subgroup, and let $\gamma = \gamma_1 + \cdots + \gamma_m$, where $\gamma_i\in\pi_1(S_{g,n})$. Then there exists $n_\gamma\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $b_{g,n}\in\mathbb{R}_+$ such that
$$\frac{\#\{\alpha\in\Gamma\cdot\gamma\;|\;\ell_\alpha(X)\le L\}}{L^{6g-6+2n}}\sim [\text{Mod}_{g,n}:\Gamma]\times n_\gamma\frac{B(X)}{b_{g,n}}$$
as $L\leadsto\infty$.
Note that if you replace $\Gamma$ with a smaller subgroup, the left hand side gets smaller, but the right hand side seems to get bigger. Is there a typo in this theorem statement? I'm confused.

I don't think that's a problem; the $\eta_\gamma$ and $b_{g,n}$ will change accordingly if you change $\Gamma$.

@NoahSchweber Are you sure? In Remark 3 following the theorem, the author indicates that $b_{g,n}$ does not depend on $\Gamma$, and in section 1.5, she also seems to indicate the $n_\gamma$'s don't depend on $\Gamma$...

@NoahSchweber The same issue seems to happy in Corollary 3.1 of the same paper. In that case it's explicit that none of the other variables are affected by $\Gamma_0$.

My guess is that one of the terms has something to do with integrating over the covering space of $\Gamma$ (so they are not independent)
